# Ajax Header value is return null. but postman show header value in below code how to get header value "Authorization"

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, api

for backend I'm using Laravel 8, Below Code in front end response header "Authorization" value is return "null" value but in postman showing value in the header section.

```
$("#but_submit").click(function(){
                var username = $("#txt_uname").val().trim();
                var password = $("#txt_pwd").val().trim();
             
                if( username != "" && password != "" ){
                    $.ajax({
                        url:'https://localhost:8000/api/login',
                        method:'GET',
                        async:true,
                        crossDomain:true,
                        data:{username:username,password:password},
                        headers: { 'Content-Type':'application/json;charset=utf-8','accept':'application/json'},
                        success:function(response,textstatus,header){
                            console.log(header.getResponseHeader('Authorization'));
                            
                        },error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                        console.error(url_link, status, err.toString());
}
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: There must be some difference between how you call this on Postman VS Ajax. For example, are you sure the method is GET? Usually POST is more common for authentication. If that's not the case, try to debug, with `console.log(response);console.log(header);` in the success function.

Comment: @AndreaOlivato Yes i'm using Get method

Comment: @AndreaOlivato when I use POST method showing error 401 (Unauthorized).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. I got an error because Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).

step 1: run composer

```
composer remove barryvdh/laravel-cors fruitcake/laravel-cors
composer require fruitcake/laravel-cors
```

Setp 2: add middleware in path

> app/Http/Kernel.php

```
\Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
```

Step 3: Publish Vendor

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag="cors"
```

Step 4: modify Config/core.php

```
'exposed_headers' => ['Authorization','Content-Type','accept'],
```